# WP-CLI error in connecting to the database

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp, wp-cli

This is a very common wp-cli error while using MAMP. I installed wp-cli, exported the php version MAMP is using to the WP_CLI_PHP variable as recommended by the instructions. The output of `$ wp --info` is:

```
PHP binary: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php
PHP version:    5.6.2
php.ini used:   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 0.20.1
```

I've followed along with all the solutions for this, but I'm still getting a timeout and error in connecting to the database. I also have MAMP running while running wp-cli commands. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing a comment [here](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues) about the issues that if-statements can have for wp-cli when used in the wp-config file, I went back and checked mine. The config file was using a number of if-statements to set the $config_file variable. I commented out this entire block and simply set the `$config_file = "path_to_config"`. This seems to have done the trick.